# Is the maximum likelihood estimator an unbiased estimator?

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

> Given is a random sample $X_1, .., X_n$ drawn from a distribution with the pdf $$ f(x; \theta) = \left\{
> \begin{array}{ll}
>       \dfrac{1}{4} e^{-\dfrac{1}{4}(x-\theta)} & \theta < x \\
>       0 & \text{otherwise} \\
> \end{array} 
> \right.  $$
>
> with an unknown paramter $\theta$ $(0 < \theta)$. Find the maximum likelihood estimator (MLE) and determine whether or not it's unbiased.

So for the MLE I found $X_{1:N}$, since the derivative of the likelihood function is $\dfrac{n}{4}$ with $n>0$, which is always positive so the likelihood function is increasing, which means we should choose the maximum value of $\theta$ possible to maximise the function. Our restriction is $\theta < x$, so the maximum we can choose is $X_{1:n}$.

However, for determining its unbiasedness I'm not completely sure. We want to show I guess that $E[X_{1:n}] = \theta$, but I don't really know what to do with the expression $E[X_{1:n}]$ to be able to write it in an appropriate form including $\theta$. How should this be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be intuitively obvious that such an estimator is necessarily biased, because it can never be smaller than the true value of $\theta$.  If it were, then you would observe $$\hat\theta_{\text{MLE}} = X_{1:n} = \min_i X_i \le \theta,$$ which is absurd.  So if there is a nonzero probability that the MLE is greater than $\theta$ (which of course is the case), it must be biased since $\Pr[\hat \theta_{\text{MLE}} < \theta] = 0.$

Comment: Why is $\theta \geq \min X_i$ absurd, exactly? I'm missing something here.

Comment: Your PDF stipulates that $\Pr[X < \theta] = 0$, does it not?  That implies no realizations you draw from such a distribution can ever be less than $\theta$; consequently the minimum order statistic also cannot be less than $\theta$, and your MLE is also never less than $\theta$.  So how can the MLE be unbiased; i.e., $\operatorname{E}[\hat\theta_{\text{MLE}}] = \theta$ if it is greater than $\theta$ with positive probability but never less than it?

Comment: This is true, I used this property to obtain the MLE. But now I'm confused because the restriction is $\theta < x$, not $\theta < X_i$ for all $i$, which I read it as...

Comment: $X_i$ is simply the $i^{\rm th}$ observation in your sample.  It too follows the same distribution as $X$.  The point is, **no observations in your sample can be smaller than $\theta$**.  So your MLE, which relies on picking the smallest observation in your sample, is always bigger than the parameter $\theta$, therefore its expectation cannot be equal to $\theta$.

Comment: You're right, the notation confused me again. I get it now.